# CircleCI 2.0 is running test workflow twice

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

The workflow configuration in my `.circleci/config.yml` file looks like this:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  test-and-deploy-if-tagged:
    jobs:
      - build-and-test:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /.*/
      - deploy-to-qa:
          filters:
            tags:
              only: /^deploy.*/
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
```

The `deploy-to-qa` workflow includes:

```
  deploy-to-qa:
    requires:
      - build-and-test
```

On a regular `master` commit the `build-and-test` workflow runs. This is what I want.

When I'm ready to cut a build, I…

- make a new commit to bump the version number
- tag the new commit (e.g. `deploy-build-123`)

After I push the new commit and tag, CircleCI runs `build-and-test` twice and `deploy-to-qa` once.

How can I configure it so a tagged release runs `build-and-test` only once, and if it passes, then run `deploy-to-qa`?

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering why this happens for almost 4 years now and I finally did something about it. One of my findings was this [entry in CircleCI Discuss](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/tagged-workflow-runs-twice/26599) where the same person (I believe) gives the (with all due respect and IMHO) same useless answer.

I end up understanding that the [annotated tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) counts as a commit (it seems) and that's why CI is run twice.

In my case I use [npm-version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version) to tag and commit and what worked for me was adding to the commit message "[skip ci]".

```
"deploy": "npm version --preid build prerelease --message 'New build: %s [skip ci]'",
"postversion": "git push --follow-tags",
```

See:

[image]

I guess you don't care about this question anymore but hopefully this new answer can help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

What's happening is exactly what's supposed to happen.

> After I push the new commit and tag

The commit runs `build-and-test` as you wanted and the tag runs both, as you wanted.

Comment: I don't want `build-and-test` to run twice on a tagged commit. How do I express that in the `config.yml` file?